# CGPDFPageRef special characters

Tags: ios, parsing, pdf

I am trying to parse some PDF files to get the texts from it, but I have some problems with reading special characters like :  ț ă â ' " and others.

I have next operators :

```
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (table, "MP", &op_MP)
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (table, "DP", &op_DP)

CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (table, "BMC", &op_BMC)
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (table, "BDC", &op_BDC)
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (table, "EMC", &op_EMC)
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "TJ", arrayCallback)
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "Tj", stringCallback)
```

Instead of those special characters, I get Ñ Ó ß and so on...
Is there something I miss?

Thanks

Comment: so what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The parameters for TJ and Tj operators (and the other text show operators) are not actual strings but byte arrays. The bytes in these arrays should be translated into characters based on font's Encoding and ToUnicode cmap (if available).
You also have to handle the Tf operator which sets the active font. Based on the font id provided as parameter you locate the font object in the /Resources dictionary. The font object contains the necessary entries for decoding correctly the parameters of TJ/Tj.
[PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten) framework is a good start for inspiration.

Reading the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) (section 9.10 and related) is a must for implementing text extraction from PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

In the pdf file, characters are represented by their glyph code in their font. Fonts can use an arbitrary encoding, so there is no guarantee that the glyph code will correspond to the Unicode codepoint for the glyph, or even that a glyph *has* a Unicode codepoint. (For example, many fonts include ligatures and alternate forms of certain letters.) It can get quite complicated.

There may (should) be some indication about how to translate glyph codes to Unicode. There might be an explicit glyph-to-Unicode map, or the font might be using a standard Unicode-to-glyph encoding. The information should be in the font dictionary, so you need to know which font the characters are being rendered with.

Unfortunately, I don't know how you would access this information using the Quartz 2D framework.

Comment: thanks for answer. This is more complicated than I thought :)